# First Facebook comment doesn't appear immediately after posting, only after page refresh

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

In addition, comment.create event doesn't fire with first added comment.

Second and all the next comments appears immediately and event fires. 
So I need first comment, then page reload for further proper plugin working.

I'm using HTML5-way to declare plugin:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{myPageURL}" data-num-posts="10" data-width="730" data-notify="true"></div>
```

Have any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** Bug description on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/370026349696283